# exe made from pyinstaller invokes another python script which does not find modules that are bundled in the exe

Tags: python, windows, process, python-asyncio, pyinstaller

I created an exe using Pyintstaller (running on Windows) which also has all the python modules. Now this .exe calls another python file(using asyncio.create_subprocess) which when running gives NoModule found error. But I can see they are contained in the bundle.

Basically fileA.exe (made using pyinstaller) has module1 bundled together. And when I try to import module1 from fileA, it works. Now there is a fileB.py, which fileA.exe does not have, is being called by fileA.exe, fileB.py does not file module1 and throws a no module found error. I want fileB.py to find module1 in the fileA.exe's bundle

I tried copying the environment (os.environ.copy()) and pass it to the subprocess. Somehow, this is not working

Comment: does your subprocess call invoke the python executable?  If so then that is your issue.

Comment: no the subprocess calls another fileB.py file

Comment: How does it call the fileB.py file without invoking the python executable?

Comment: ah yes, it calls python executable... and I meant it does not call fileB.exe.
But in this case, shouldn't it be the case for all the imports that are not available in site-packages of python (machine level)

Comment: can my python executable pick up .pyd files somehow?

Comment: Pyinstaller doesn't bundle a python executable in it's output.  So unless the system you are running the .exe on already has python pre-installed any subprocess calls that invoke the python executable will not work.

Comment: Yes, I have python exe installed on that system. But can I make that python pick up the .pyd (or even .dll) files while trying to import. For example, in this case, fileB.py pick up module1.pyd instead of looking in the site-packages of system?

Comment: That I don't know...  probably.  But there is likely a better solution to your problem